# Android Developer Tools code generation for Views like Buttons, textfields

Tags: android, developer-tools, findviewbyid

Does the following feature exist in Android Developer Tools.

After you have created your XML layout, is there a quick way to quickly import those views into your java code automatically.

This is to save you typing in the

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search)
```

Is there some short cut which will automatically generate this code by looking at my XML file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the exact answer but look at [roboguice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/). It's dependency injection framework for Android.

```
class RoboWay extends RoboActivity { 
@InjectView(R.id.name)             TextView name; 
@InjectView(R.id.thumbnail)        ImageView thumbnail; 
@InjectResource(R.drawable.icon)   Drawable icon; 
@InjectResource(R.string.app_name) String myName; 
@Inject                            LocationManager loc; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    name.setText( "Hello, " + myName ); 
} 
}
```

Comment: As well AndroidAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

No. Sorry.

What are you trying to accomplish by finding all of your views? Maybe there is another shortcut that will help you.

Comment: well the old MOTODEV studio for Android (which does not exist anymore) it was based on Eclipse had this feature. Basically I could select to auto generate code for all the views that my java code was associated to. Its nothing more than a shortcut. I thought it was possible in Eclipse I guess not.